# Card edge connector and perfboard for EEPROM cartridges

Tags: connector, prototyping, protoboard

I'm working on a game console project, want to be able to load data from interchangeable 32kB serial EEPROM (24LC256) cartridges.  These ICs have an 8-pin footprint, so I need an 8-position edge connector.

And here's the tricky bit: I don't think I'm ready to order custom PCBs, so I'm wondering if there are card-edge proto/perfboards that I could use to make my cartridges by hand?  I'm a beginner, and would appreciate any good advice from pros.

Comment: If you just want to be hacking something together, you could probably bodge a 9-pin header system. Take a pin out to make the connector so that it only goes in one way.

Comment: That makes sense, I could use a right-angle header instead of a plugboard.  I'm guessing I should put my +3.3V line opposite of the unused line so that nothing gets power if the cartridge is inserted backwards.

Comment: @amoss What Daniel is suggesting isn't that you leave one pin unused - he's suggesting that you remove one of the pins entirely and leave something in the socket to block a pin from entering that space.

Comment: If you're okay with something a little "soft", there are MSOP-8 to SIP adapters that you might be able to use without pins, with the SIP pad acting as an edge connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and clone or use something like the following small serial FLASH breakout boards/modules.

Also remember that you can usually get away with just 4 or 5 connections and this might give you ideas for making a smaller connector choice.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/182238847961?item=182238847961&lgeo=1&vectorid=229466&rmvSB=true

http://www.zeppy.io/discover/us/i2c-eeprom

http://www.piccircuit.com/shop/pic-io-board/60-icm13-eeprom-module.html